# Fixed format regex: [aaa-aaaa]

Tags: java, regex

I have a fixed format such as xxx-xxxx. Which is 3 alphanumeric then a dash then 4 alphanumeric. I am new to regex. I would like to know how i can carry this checking on regex for java.

I know that for /w is for any word, /d for any digit. And x{n} for n number of occurences. But how do i put all these together? Thanks.

Comment: You have all the "knowledge" you need but you can't put them together? Guess what `\w{3}` does. Then guess what `\w{3}-` does. Now try to complete the puzzle.

Comment: `"\\w{3}-\\w{4}"` you can use

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera -1, you ruined the (fun) puzzle for the OP :p

Comment: @HamZa There isn't such fun here.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
Pattern.compile("\\p{Alnum}{3}-\\p{Alnum}{4}");
```

Comment: Could you explain the syntax? Thanks

Comment: @ps4one `\p{Alnum}` is a POSIX character class that stands for any alphanumeric character (simply `[\w]`). The number inside curly braces sets the expected number of characters. And the dash is just a dash.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}-[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$
```

You can try this.Do not forget to put the anchors.

Comment: it matches `_` also. Op says clearly that it's a alphanumeric string.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try : http://rubular.com
It has better pattern compilation and display.

The answer for this is : `^\w{3}-\w{4}$`

Comment: "better pattern compilation" this sentence might be misleading. Could you expand on that? Anyways, he's using Java and rubular.com is a ruby regex tester. In most simple cases it's acceptable but if you dive a little bit deeper you will notice differences in Java vs Ruby regex.

Comment: it matches `_` also. Op says clearly that it's a alphanumeric string.

Comment: Yes HamZa, There are differences in Java and Ruby regex.(In Ruby we write regexes by delimiting them with /, and in Java you need to double-escape everything (\\ instead of \) so that the backslashes get through to the regex engine) 
I would correct myself on the pattern compilation where I mean better visualisation of the regex verity for provided input.

I was just being helpful, as I personally like rubular and usually tweak the irregularities accordingly.